# Legal to post an image of a textbook for help?

Tags: legal-issues, education, law

I had a textbook problem that I wasn't able to solve, so I posted the question on a social media platform and got asked to provide an image of the entire page including the question by multiple people, so I did, and deleted the image after the conversation was done. Was this illegal? Is it considered as fair use, since it's for educational purposes?

Comment: Better to ask it on Law.SE. Legal stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that almost everywhere and for most situations copyright is a civil matter and it is up to a copyright holder to make a claim in court. Sharing such material privately is fine (most places) under "fair use", which isn't recognized everywhere.

And, fair use, where it is recognized, is a bit broader for educational use, but not unlimited or absolute. It is a matter of judgement.

However, if your sharing on "social media" is a form of publishing (making public) then it might be a technical violation but extremely unlikely to be charged as it is a small (if any) violation, not worth the effort of filing a law suit.

It is probably best not to do such things, but not something to worry too much about. Sharing off-line would be fine, but most social media sites are open to the public for many things. A private message on a site is likely not an issue.

Note that one consideration in copyright law (which varies from place to place) is whether an act reduces the value of the copied material. That doesn't seem to be the case here, but only a jury (or judge) could say and only if a suit were filed.

---

Caveat: IIRC there are a few places and some situations in this big world where copyright is a matter of criminal, not civil, law. What you describe doesn't seem to fall in to that category (in the US, anyway).

Comment: Re: criminal aspect of copyright infringement. Canada for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Act_(Canada)#Penalties

Comment: In the UK, importing an infringing copy is a criminal matter, and uploads/downloads to/from social media sites are pretty likely to cross international borders.